# pre tag inside class

Tags: css, html, pre

Show below picture. I want to show left side content in this format. So I have used pre tag. But problem is when I resize the browser both division are merged. And text are not readable. How to solve this proble?

first image for text not readable and second that I want.
[image] [image]

Comment: Could you show us your code? (html & css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your code looks like but i think this will help you.

You could give the class you're using vore the text on the left a `margin-right:50%;` in your css.

```
p.maintext_left {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-right:50%;
}
```

If this doesn't help you please show me your code.

Comment: can you give your mail id?

Comment: Sure but why not edit your post and put the code in here?frankwinters123@gmail.com

Comment: i have send code through mail